# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException Error for android below Androdi 6

Tags: android, android-studio, android-contentprovider, android-appcompat

**Hi Professional. I need help.**

I was testing my android on the test lab firebase, and I got below errors :

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0700cc
     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mathar.tvonlineindonesia, PID: 7449
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0700cc
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2598)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.loadDrawableFromDelegates(ResourceManagerInternal.java:252)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:139)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
    at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:505)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.initialize(ActionMenuItemView.java:126)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.bindItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:207)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getItemView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:188)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.getItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:193)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.flagActionItems(ActionMenuPresenter.java:473)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.flagActionItems(MenuBuilder.java:1182)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:96)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:226)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:298)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1069)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1096)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:461)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:56)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I dont know where to start debugging this error, I found that these errors only show on android 6 and below. I found on the stackoverflow about this error but I have no clue for this. The only thing that I think there is the problem with the appcompat version, but I dont have idea for this. Hope you can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: That can happen if you have a drawable that's not available for the current Android version; e.g., if you have a drawable only in `res/drawable-v24/`, but you're testing on API level 23 or below. There might be more information that could be helpful in pinpointing the exact issue further on in that stack trace.

Comment: hello mike, thank you for your answer.I have only one drawable directory in /res/drawable and there is no like drawable-v24 or drawable-v23, any clue for this?

Comment: Do you have the complete stack trace? There should be a couple of `Cause by:` lines further on down. The issue seems to be in the options menu for whichever `Activity` it's crashing in, so that menu XML is the next thing I would start investigating.

Comment: I got the full log file here >> https://storage.cloud.google.com/test-lab-ppahjmft5t2tu-is38xu6iz72n2/web-build_2020-05-27T16%3A41%3A26.824Z_kca2/lv0-23-en_US-portrait/logcat

Comment: can you access that??

Comment: Nope: Forbidden
Error 403.

Comment: okay, wait I will upload it to pastebin

Comment: sorry for the time, I have to find the free one first LOL 

https://paste.ee/p/Z6Tru << can u access it? 

thanks in advance mike..

Comment: Really appreciate your response :)

Comment: Yeah, I can access that. Well, that is all you got from that stack trace, so there's not much more to learn from the rest of those logs. I would start looking at that options menu XML, and the drawables you've used there.

Comment: Did you figure this out Mhd? I have something very similar appearing very rarely in crashlytics. I've not been able to find the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused for API 23 and less device. The main reason for this error is when the same images of `Drawable(v24)` are not found in the `Drawable` folder. Just copy your images (.png) from `Drawable(v24)` to `Drawable` (API <23). Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the wrong placement of resources(images). You use (API 23) but resources for API 23 is null, because they only API 24 and up.
[1-photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeU7G.png)

Now all images marked (v24) this means that they are in drawables-v24 just move in drawable

[2-photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfUGa.png)